# C #define macros

Tags: c, c-preprocessor, operator-precedence

Here is what i have and I wonder how this works and what it actually does.

```
#define NUM 5
#define FTIMES(x)(x*5)

int main(void) {
    int j = 1;
    printf("%d %d\n", FTIMES(j+5), FTIMES((j+5)));
}
```

It produces two integers: 26 and 30.

How does it do that?

Answer (score 18):

The reason this happens is because your macro expands the print to:

```
printf("%d %d\n", j+5*5, (j+5)*5);
```

Meaning:

```
1+5*5 and (1+5)*5
```

Comment: That should teach a valuable lesson in avoiding #define macros for things that inline functions should actually handle.

Comment: Or, when you can't avoid them, place each occurrence of each argument in parentheses, and place the entire macro in parenthesis (that is, when your macro is an expression and not a statement)

Answer (score 13):

Since it hasn't been mentioned yet, the way to fix this problem is to do the following:

```
#define FTIMES(x) ((x)*5)
```

The parentheses around `x` in the macro expansion prevent the operator associativity problem.

Comment: that won't save you if you have multiple occurrences of the parameter in the macro and you pass in some kind of expression with side effects, like j += 3.

Answer (score 3):

## define is just a string substitution.

The answer to your question after that is order of operations:

FTIMES(j+5) =  1+5*5  = 26

FTIMES((j+5)) = (1+5)*5 = 30

Answer (score 2):

The compiler pre-process simply does a substitution of FTIMES wherever it sees it, and then compiles the code.  So in reality, the code that the compiler sees is this:

```
#define NUM 5
#define FTIMES(x)(x*5)

int main(void)
{

    int j = 1;

    printf("%d %d\n", j+5*5,(j+5)*5);
}
```

Then, taking operator preference into account, you can see why you get 26 and 30.

Comment: Technically, the compiler doesn't see the #defines. :)

Answer (score 1):

And if you want to fix it:

```
#define FTIMES(x) ((x) * 5)
```

Answer (score 0):

the preprocessor substitutes all NUM ocurrences in the code with 5, and all the FTIMES(x) with x * 5. The compiler then compiles the code.

Its just text substitution.

Answer (score 0):

Order of operations.

FTIMES(j+5) where j=1 evaluates to:

1+5*5

Which is:

25+1

=26

By making FTIMES((j+5)) you've changed it to:

(1+5)*5

6*5

30